# Circle div hover responsive and aligment issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 3 circle responsive divs. When you hover on one they get little bigger but this is executed even when you hover *near* them. Also I need them to be aligned to center with little responsive space.

I have demo here [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/x5jwvx3j/)

And my code

```
    <div id="kruhobal">
        <div class="kruh" id="kruh1"></div>
        <div class="kruh" id="kruh2"></div>
        <div class="kruh" id="kruh3"></div> 
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#kruhobal
  {
    width:100%;  
}

@media only screen and (max-width:111100px)
{
.kruh
{
  display: inline-block;
    transition: transform 1.0s ease;

}
.kruh:before
{
 border-radius:50%;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 0vw;
    width: 13vw;
    height: 13vw;
}
.kruh:hover
{
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
#kruh1
{

}
#kruh1:before
{
  background:red;
    background-size:cover;  
}


#kruh2:before
{
    background:red;
    background-size:cover;      

}
#kruh3:before
{   
    background:red;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation on your circles is getting triggered even when the mouse is outside the circle, because the element itself is a square. You can see what I mean by adding an outline to the elements in your original example.

The element is rendered as a square because you have the `:before` element as a square, and the hover event is getting triggered by that. I would suggest getting rid of the `:before` element entirely and just using the element itself, as in this snippet:

```css
.kruh {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:red;
  transition: transform 1.0s ease;
  height: 13vw;
  width: 13vw;
}
.kruh:hover {
   transform: scale(1.15);
 }
```

```html
<div id="kruhobal">
  <div class="kruh" id="kruh1"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="kruh2"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="kruh3"></div>
</div>
```

The other solution if you *need* to keep the `:before` element is to also apply the border-radius to the parent div.

To address the second part of your question "how to center the items", your best best would be flexbox, which you would apply to the parent element. I don't know what you mean by "little responsive space", but to add some space in between the items, you would give each a margin.

```css
 #kruhobal {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
 }

.kruh {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:red;
  transition: transform 1.0s ease;
  height: 13vw;
  width: 13vw;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.kruh:hover {
   transform: scale(1.15);
 }
```

```html
<div id="kruhobal">
  <div class="kruh" id="kruh1"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="kruh2"></div>
  <div class="kruh" id="kruh3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any idea how to make it full circle?

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to fix issue with aligment?

Comment: What's the problem with the alignment?

Comment: iI need they them to be aligned to center with little responsive space.

Comment: Added centering solution to answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163071/discussion-between-jakeparis-and-jac0b).